# Equivalence between AF and $AF^{*}$

Tags: set-theory

I have a problem with the proof of this:

Let $AF^{*}$ be the axiom schema $(\forall x(\forall y \in x \varphi(y) \to \varphi (x))) \to \forall x \varphi (x)$,
where the variable y does not occur in $\varphi (x)$. Show, in $ZF^{-}−Pow$, that
$AF$ and $AF^{∗}$ are equivalent.

I actually prove that $AF \implies AF^{*}$, but I don't know how to prove the other implication.

I proceed in this way:

I know  that there exists a formula $\psi$ in
the language of ZF expressing the property that x is well-founded. I pick an element a, I assume that $\forall y \in a$ $ \psi(y)$ holds and I'm trying to prove $\psi (a)$. For do this I arguin by absurd. So, suppose that a is not well founded.
At this point I would like to conclude that x is well-founded because all of his element are well founded, but I think that I can't use this fact because for prove this fact I must have the axiom of foundation. (in the lecture we prove in this way). How can I arrive at an absurdum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Let $\phi(x)$ = "every non-empty subset of $tc(x)$ is well-founded" (i.e. if $y\subseteq tc(x)$ and $y\not= \emptyset$, then there is some $z\in y$ such that $z\cap y = \emptyset$). Now, suppose that every $y\in x$ is such that $\phi(y)$ but that $\neg\phi(x)$. Then there's some non-empty $z\subseteq tc(x)$ which is non-well-founded. Let $w\in z$. Then $w = y$ or $w\in tc(y)$, for some $y\in x$. Either way, $tc(w)\cap z$ is a non-well-founded subset of $tc(y)$, contradicting our supposition.

So, we've established that for every $x$ if every $y\in x$ is $\phi$, then $x$ is $\phi$. Applying AF$^*$ we get that every subset of $tc(x)$ is well-founded; which is to say we get AF.

Comment: This is true in $\sf ZF+DC$ but not in $\sf ZF$. It is consistent that there are no infinite descending $\in$ chains, but the axiom of foundation fails (and of course, the axiom of choice fails too).

Comment: Whoops; I hadn't read the question carefully enough - in particular, I missed that the OP wanted the proof in ZF$^-$ - Powerset. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Very nice. (When I thought about it, somehow the transitive closure felt right, but I didn't pursue that direction.)

Comment: @GME: I need some clarifications: why, to reach the contradiction, do you use $tc(w)$ and not simply $w$ in the intersection $tc(w)\cap z$? In fact, $w\cap z=\varnothing$ because $w \in z$ and $z$ is not well-founded, moreover since $w \in tc(y)$, $w\subseteq tc(y)$.

Comment: @GME: I meant $w \cap z \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: @Claretta I used $tc(w)$ because in general $w\cap z$ may be well-founded (and we want our subset of $tc(y)$ to be non-well-founded to reach a contradiction). For example, suppose that $z = \{x_0,...,x_n....\}$ where $x_0 = \{x_1\},..., = \{x_n\},...$. Then $x_i \cap z$ is well-founded for any $i$.

Comment: @GME: Thank you for the answer, now I see that there could be a problem. But I don't get why $tc(w)\cap z$ is a non well-founded subset of $tc(y)$, I guess I should think about it a little bit more.

Comment: @Claretta No worries! Here's the argument. Suppose $x\in tc(w) \cap z$. Since $z$ is non-well-founded, there is some $t\in x\cap z$. But since $x\in tc(w)$, $t\in tc(w)$, and so $t\in tc(w)\cap z$. So, $tc(w)\cap z$ is non-well-founded.